# Hive joining tables with partitions

Tags: sql, hive

I need to optimize a query in Hive where I am joining tables using partitions but using two different partitions:

```
select *
from k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_item_dim a inner
join k1_repl_dl_tables.repl_managed_sku b on b.mds_fam_id = a.mds_fam_id
join k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_store_club_dim c on c.store_nbr = b.store_nbr inner
join k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_calendar_dim d on current_date = d.cal_dt
group by c.state_prov_cd, a.upc_nbr, a.item_nbr, a.signing_desc, a.dept_nbr, b.store_nbr, c.store_nm, d.cal_wk_nbr
limit 10;
```

the partitions would be:

for k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_item_dim, k1_repl_dl_tables.repl_managed_sku and k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_store_club_dim, partition op_cmpny_cd=WMT-K1

for k1_core_dim_dl_tables.dl_calendar_dim, partition geo_region_cd=K1

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to achieve as it is not clear what the relevance of the partition information you have provided is to the SQL statement. How do you know that the SQL statement is not already as optimised as it could be? Partitions are only of relevance if you have a WHERE clause that filters on the column(s) that define the partitioning logic

Comment: @NickW I am running this query extracting data from a data lake using Hue and someone told me that in order to reduce the time Hue takes to process this query, that I should use partitions for better performance. This is the first time I am using partitions, so it doesn't has much sense to me yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive you can partition a table by a column (or group of columns), so you might partition a transaction table by date (or even by date and hour if it was very large). If you then write a query that filters by the partitioning columns it will only scan the in-scope partitions rather than the full table. So if you queried your transaction table where transaction date = 2020-12-04 it would only scan a single partition.

So partitioning can help with query performance but it has limitations, mainly that if you filter a query by anything other than partitioning column then you still need to do a full table scan e.g. query your transaction table where customer ='ABC' and amount > 1000 would do a full table scan

BTW - you can only have one partitioning structure per table

Hope this helps?